# Find .Include() chains using Visual Studio Regex Search

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have recently been asked to take over a large LOB application that uses Entity Framework.  Many of the db calls being made use several (>5) Includes, which causes some very heavy query inefficiency.  I want to use Visual Studio's search functionality to find some of these include chains.  As a quick example, one might look like:

```
var res = ObjectContext.Items.Include("Details")
             .Include("Users").Include("Users.Info");
```

I'd like to find any instance of more than 1 include, and match regardless of what the include path is.

How can I structure a search to identify these chains?  Any help is most appreciated!

Comment: Why can't you just use Visual Studio to find the occurrences? Further, do you understand the reason why EF requires `Include()` method calls? You can't just go removing them because you feel they are a performance problem.

Comment: Is there any common beginning to these instances? i.e. They always start with "ObjectContext.".  I ask as I have been burned before by find/replace in VS with over-broad regex queries.

Comment: @keyboardP, you have it, I want to use Regex to identify the chains, not just a single instance.  There are several hundred instances.

Comment: @GrantH. which version are you using? the regex flavor greatly differs between VS2012 and previous versions.

Comment: @Yuck, there are enough that there would be considerable benefit to finding only the chained ones, not single instances.  And yes, I know how Includes work, but you can break up the chains to significantly improve performance, which is what I intend to do.

Comment: @GrantH. also, are any arguments to `Include` complex expressions or are they always strings?

Comment: @m.buettner, I'm using VS2012, and they are always strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS2012 uses .NET's regex flavor so you could do something like

```
(?:[.]Include[(]\s*"[^"]*"\s*[)]\s*){2,}
```

This matches one `.Include("something")` plus any white space after it and then requires at least two repetitions of this pattern. Note that you'll get problems if your strings contain quotes or you have verbatim strings in there. In that case the `"[^"]*"` would have to be a bit more elaborate.

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for, thank you!